# Google chrome is redirecting any search result to a custom Search engine

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, search, redirection

There is a problem when I use the search engine google.com.
any search I did on Google chrome using google.com is redirecting me to a custom search engine [cse.google.com](https://cse.google.com)
Let's say I would like to search for "Paris"
this url is what I get

`https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-2489853033595080:6244593931&q=fdsfsd&oq=fdsfsd&gs_l=partner-generic.12...0.0.0.99.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.gsnos%2Cn%3D13...0.0....34.partner-generic..0.0.0.`

it is a very weird layout

I do not want that

and I tried to reset my browser to the default setting without any progress
I even tried to rest google search engine and try to configure an new google one without any luck. I updated my antispayware and my google chrome, but for nothing.
I tried use IE edge it have the same problem while firefox is clean. that's make me think it is not something on my windows 10.

I have check my system, and it is clean from viruses.

Please help how to fix that issue?

Comment: How did you check that your system is clean from viruses? When did this start, and what changes were made just before then?

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050 I have fixed the problem ... and for the god sake for documenting the solution .. the problem raised when I uninstalled my Internet security and reinstall it with a new licenses. It seems that is was a memory resident script and ran when my Internet security was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem. With [Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdevbuilds.kaspersky-labs.com%2Fdevbuilds%2FKVRT%2Flatest%2Ffull%2FKVRT.exe&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEcVH3JziWbNUNMlK2d2OHPghAHzw)

After the scan the software found a couples of Trojans and one script resident in memory and the removable tool cure it (something different than deleting things). and before rebooting I have checked google chrome and Internet Explorer and I found that everything ran smoothly as expected.

I reboot and the Removable tool continue to check my system as a final step with no Viruses found.

The steps that @Sam3000 mentioned didn't really help maybe because the problem was a malscript resident in memory. and the script is not a really harmful virus.

Comment: Did you try Malwarebytes, and did it find anything? Or was it not tried?

Comment: yes I did and it didn't find anything .. I also tried super anti spyware with no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the update on this, interesting result! Your suspicions about the script being resident in memory and hence not being identified are likely spot on, but I would have expected Malwarebytes to have identified the trojans... Anyway, glad you sorted it :)

Answer (score 6):

This is likely an example of "[Potentialy Unwanted Program](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/PUP)" (PUP) malware, which often gets installed alongside a program you intended to install - usually because the installer includes a *tiny* checkbox which must be cleared to prevent the installation of the PUP.

Unfortunately, some programs designed to prevent or remove virus/spyware/adware/malware infections don't pickup PUPs by default.

If you tried to reset the search engine without success it strongly suggests something is running on your system to overwrite any changes you make.

There is a rather comprehensive (but fairly simple) guide on how to resolve this issue at the link below:

[How to remove a Cse.google.com redirect](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-cse-google-com/)

In summary:

1. Look through your installed programs and uninstall suspected PUPs. **If you are unsure whether or not to remove a program, please research the name of it first.**

Examples of PUPs include:

*Search Module, Search Module Plus or Google.Vc, OtherSearches, YeaDesktop, Wajam, 1.0.0.1, DNS Unlocker, Cinema Plus, Price Minus, SalesPlus, New Player, MediaVideosPlayers, Browsers_Apps_Pro, PriceLEess, Pic Enhance, Sm23mS, Salus, Network System Driver, SS8, Save Daily Deals, Word Proser, Desktop Temperature Monitor, CloudScout Parental Control, Savefier, Savepass, HostSecurePlugin, CheckMeUp or HD-V2.2.*

2. Reboot
3. Reset your search engine/browser settings to the desired state.

If you are unable to identify the culprit PUP, [Malwarebytes](https://malwaretips.com/download-malwarebytes) can be installed and used to scan for PUPs.